# How to output the top 5 of a specific column along with associated columns using python?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I've tried to use `df2.nlargest(5, ['1960']` this gives me:

```
          Country Name Country Code  ...            2017            2018
0     IDA & IBRD total          IBT  ... 6335039629.0000 6412522234.0000
1  Low & middle income          LMY  ... 6306560891.0000 6383958209.0000
2        Middle income          MIC  ... 5619111361.0000 5678540888.0000
3            IBRD only          IBD  ... 4731120193.0000 4772284113.0000
6  Upper middle income          UMC  ... 2637690770.0000 2655635719.0000
```

This is somewhat right, but it's outputting all the columns. I just want it to include the column name "Country Name" and "1960" only, but sort by the column "1960."

So the output should look like this...

```
Country Name         1960
China                5000000000
India                499999999
USA                  300000
France               100000
Germany              90000
```

Comment: just add slicing after `nlargest` as  `df2.nlargest(5,  '1960')[['Country Name', '1960']]`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! I had code before it that messed once I deleted it worked.